# specify other platforms app icons in phonegap ios

Tags: ios, cordova

I built the app using phonegap with xcode 4.5 .Basically i chosen the template as PhoneGap based application.And create the simple app successfully installed the apps in deveices(iPad & Android mobile).I could see only default icon on all devices.How to specify that?Do i need to modify in phonegap.plist?

Answer (score 0):

Each platform has its own way of handling the application icon, so you'll have to do some more work than just updating one file.

Did you see [phonegap's wiki on that topic](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Icon-Sizes)?

Comment: Can any one share me sample config.xml for ios which include the configuration of app icons for all devices?App got crashed when i include the below code in config.xml                                     `<icon src="icon/ios/icon-57.png" />
    <icon src="icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />`